# WCF Data Service Override Select Data

Tags: wcf, service, odata

I just watched [Scott Hanselman's video on OData](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ODataBasicsAtTheAZGroupsDayOfNETWithScottGu.aspx) and was blown away by it.

I've done my own solution based on his example and I want to override the default Get Data methods.  What I'd like to do is to look at the query which is being executed and override the GetCustomers SP call if the query is simple such as;

```
from c in Customers where c.customerid = 12
```

Basically I don't want to get all the table from SQL every time someone runs the service.  Any ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Every entity set fetching can be intercepted by what is known as Interceptors. Take a look at them and see if thats what you are trying to do. The interceptors allow you to intercept the calls to the entity set and do some customized logics. Check it out